# How to make the variable available in the methods of the class?

Tags: javascript

I apologize for this question, just starting to learn Javascript.

I have 2 methods:

```
Manager.prototype.filters = function () {
         var user = [];
           ...

Manager.prototype.filters_main = function () {
         var user = [];
           ...
```

I need to make the property 'user' available to the 2 methods (filters, filters_main). So that they can use the shared variable (user). 
**How it is possible to write?**

Comment: Put it in the body: `function Manager() { this.user = [];`

Comment: Between Manager.prototype. ...?
And what I should write in prototypes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the prototype-based inheritance here.

```
var Manager = function() {
    this.user = [];
}

var manager = new Manager();
```

These lines will define a `Manager` constructor function and create a new object. When you call the `new Manager()`, what happens is:

1. a new, empty, object is created: `{}`.
2. the code inside the constructor will run with this new, empty, object being the value of `this`. So, it will set the `user` property of the new object (`{}`) to be an empty array.
3. the `__proto__` property of the new object will be set to the value of Manager.prototype. So, this happens without you seeing: `manager.__proto__ = Manager.prototype`.

Then, you want to define new methods on your prototype objects, using the inheritance. Keep in mind that the prototype is a plain JS object. Not a constructor, but an object. So every object created from the `Manager` function will have its `__proto__` property set to *the same* object.

Then, you start defining new methods on the prototype object, like the `filters` function. When you, later, call `manager.filters()`, it will first look up its own properties for the `filters` function and won't find it. So, then, it will go for its prototype properties, and there if will find it. `manager` will then run the `filters` function that was defined on the prototype, but using itself (`manager`) as the context, as the `this` inside the function.

So, to use your `user` property inside the `filters` function, all you have to do is:

```
Manager.prototype.filters = function () {
     this.user = ...;
}

Manager.prototype.filters_main = function () {
     this.user = ...;
}
```

and you'll be manipulating the same `user` property defined when the object was constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable in your `Manager` definition:

```
function Manager() {
    this.user = [];
}
```

And now you should be able to use it in your filter functions:

```
Manager.prototype.filters = function() {
    // Use it:
    if (this.user.indexOf(...) != -1) {
        ...
    }
};
```

Then you can continue as normal:

```
var manager = new Manager();
manager.user = ["user1", "user2"];
var filters = manager.filters();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the body:

```
function Manager() { 
   this.user = []; 
}

Manager.prototype.filters = function () {
   alert(this.user)
}

var m = new Manager();
m.user = [11,22,33]
m.filters();
```